# Controls having a Generic constructor Type<T>

Tags: c#, winforms

I have the following class which is to be callied in different custom controls. These controls custom have the look of winforms. Controls are each of type Control1, control2...Can I have a generic constructor of Type  where T could be 
Namespace.C1,  Namespace.C2, Namespace.C3, Namespace.C4..., Namespace.C8

Question:  SimpleDirtyTracker _tracker = new SimpleDirtyTracker(Type) where  T is a usercontrol with lots of textboxes, instead of 
  SimpleDirtyTracker _tracker = new SimpleDirtyTracker(Form frm),

```
  public class SimpleDirtyTracker
    {
      private Form _frmTracked;  
      private bool _isDirty;

      // property denoting whether the tracked form is clean or dirty
      public bool IsDirty
      {
          get { return _isDirty; }
          set { _isDirty = value; }
      }

      // methods to make dirty or clean
      public void SetAsDirty()
      {
          _isDirty = true;
      }

      public void SetAsClean()
      {
          _isDirty = false;
      }


//Needs a generic type in the constructor. Not a form, mostly a user control of type Namespace.Control1 or Namespace.Control2
      public SimpleDirtyTracker(SomeType T) where T is a custom control
      {
          _frmTracked = frm;
          AssignHandlersForControlCollection(frm.Controls);
      }


      // recursive routine to inspect each control and assign handlers accordingly
      private void AssignHandlersForControlCollection(Control.ControlCollection coll)
      {
          foreach (Control c in coll)
          {
              if (c is TextBox)
                  (c as TextBox).TextChanged += new EventHandler(SimpleDirtyTracker_TextChanged);

              if (c is CheckBox)
                  (c as CheckBox).CheckedChanged += new EventHandler(SimpleDirtyTracker_CheckedChanged);

              // ... apply for other input types similarly ...

              // recurively apply to inner collections
              if (c.HasChildren)
                  AssignHandlersForControlCollection(c.Controls);
          }
      }

      // event handlers
      private void SimpleDirtyTracker_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
      {
          _isDirty = true;
      }

      private void SimpleDirtyTracker_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
      {
          _isDirty = true;
      }

    }
}
```

This class will be called from custom controls. These are mostly controls with textboxes used as Winforms

```
     private void Control_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
            {
                // in the Load event initialize our tracking object
//To Pass a generic type.   //Needs a generic type in the constructor. Type T could be Namespace.C1...Namespace.C8

                _dirtyTracker = new SimpleDirtyTracker(Custom Control T);
                _dirtyTracker.SetAsClean();
            }
```

Comment: Yes, How do I pass in a generic type to the constructor.. Instead of giving it a specific type like Form, I would like to say, SimpleDirtyTracker _tracker = new SimpleDirtyTracker(Type<T>) where  T is a usercontrol with lots of textboxes

Comment: The UI is not the right place for `IsDirty` type of stuff. That's the problem with winforms, that it forces you to all sorts of horrible anti-patterns because it doesn't allow a true separation of UI and data. I suggest you research on the MVP pattern, which is as good as it gets in winforms, or otherwise use current technologies that support much cleaner patterns such as WPF and MVVM.

Comment: What's wrong with specifying type as the class generic type argument? what you want to do is only useful for design time check, because we can always use some code to check the type at runtime.